# Print Preview with PuTTY

Tags: ssh, security, printing, putty, network-protocols

PuTTY is a very good application, but it doesn't have printing options, or maybe I don't know them.
Can anyone help me? It's really necessary to preview what we are going to print.

Another option is NetTerm, but it only works with the Telnet protocol, which isn't secure enough for me. SNetTerm is a very alternative, but unfortunately I cannot spend money on this.

Comment: Some printer drivers offer a preview feature. Did you check that yet?

Comment: Not yet, I trying everything, and I will try what you just suggested. Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you want to print? The terminal screen of PuTTY? How do you print it if there's no preview function?

Comment: Well, I wnat to print a report generated by a server. I finally got the solution on linux, I made a little program on gambas, that allow the previsualization before printing, and from PuTTy>Terminal, I put a command line to call that gambas program. But on windows it's something different

Comment: I really don't know the command equivalent for windows (XD), but I'm looking for that. Anyway this is the command: "cat > temp && /home/asesor_2_26/Editor.gambas temp". But, I have to generate an .exe for Windows, well I guess... I'm still working on that.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a work around:**

You can configure PuTTY session logging and save the file on the desktop as `output.html`.

Open the web browser and install a extension called reload and open the `output.html` file and set the reload every 5 seconds.

Every time when you execute a command on your PuTTY, your screen output is logged in `output.html` file and this is reloaded every 5 seconds. Hence you can watch your PuTTY output on terminal and web browser. If you require a copy of the output, change the `.html to`.txt`.